# node js function name is not always defined

Tags: node.js, function

I need to get the name of functions by accessing it from its object.

Normally something like this works:

`s=''
s.splice.name`

in fact it returns `slice`, that is correct but if I do `require('child_process').exec` I get `''`

Is there a way to achieve the task I need?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every function has to have a name.

Node is actually pretty smart about setting the `name` property even for some anonymous unnamed functions, but it's not always possible.

See this in the Node repl:

```
> x = function x() {};
[Function: x]
> x.name
'x'
> y = function () {};
[Function: y]
> y.name
'y'
> z = () => {};
[Function: z]
> z.name
'z'
> w = (() => () => {})();
[Function]
> w.name
''
```

The last function doesn't have any name. It's not that I access it in a wrong way, it's just that Node doesn't know the name at all so there is no way for me to get it.

Comment: therefore, do you think there's a way to get a fingerprint from functions and distinguish them? my goal should be that